# Static action and Break from Java 8 stream forEach on HashMap?

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, foreach, java-8

When using external iteration over an Iterable we use static action and Break from enhanced for-each loop as:

```
for (Entry<String, String> w : Context.getWindows().entrySet()) {
    if (w.getValue().equals(Context.getDriver().getWindowHandle())) {
        Context.removeWindow(w.getKey());
        break;
    }
}
Context.getDriver().close();
```

How can we break or return using the internal iteration in a Java 8 lambda expression like:

```
Context.getWindows().forEach(obj -> {
   //what to do here?
})
```

I find other question on https://stackoverflow.com with `stream()` `filter` and `findFirst` but this solution return a object. In my case I want execute a static action and break;

```
Optional<SomeObject> result =
    Context.getWindows().stream().filter(obj -> some_condition_met).findFirst();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should translate to something like

```
Context.getWindows().entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue().equals(Context.getDriver().getWindowHandle()))
    .map(e -> e.getKey())
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(k -> Context.removeWindow(k));
Context.getDriver().close();
```

Or, more concise

```
Context.getWindows().entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue().equals(Context.getDriver().getWindowHandle()))
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(Context::removeWindow);
Context.getDriver().close();
```